# Copying text from one textbox to one on another form and sorting between textboxes

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I am still learning on vb.net but I have main form (form1) that has 2 columns. One called Red and the other Yellow. I have a button that opens a form (form2) that has a textbox that allows the user to put in someone's name and a combobox to select a color. What I am trying to accomplish it when they click the submit button on form2, the name will show up in the proper column in form1. Both colors on form1 has their own textbox under it. Red has textbox1 and Yellow has textbox2. Can anyone assist on how I would go about doing this? I am using Visual Studio 2010 VB.Net. Thanks!!

Danny

Comment: So are textbox1 and textbox2 multi-line textboxes?...and you simply append the name entered in form2 to the correct one based on the colored selected?

Comment: Yes both textbox1 and textbox2 are multi-line and yes I am wanting the names sorted by color on form1 based on what was entered and selected in form2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many ways to do this...here's another one.

Code in Form1:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim f2 As New Form2
        If f2.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Select Case f2.ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString.ToLower
                Case "red"
                    TextBox1.AppendText(f2.TextBox1.Text & Environment.NewLine)

                Case "yellow"
                    TextBox2.AppendText(f2.TextBox1.Text & Environment.NewLine)

                Case Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Unkown Color!")

            End Select
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

and in Form2:

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If TextBox1.TextLength > 0 AndAlso ComboBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

From a simple workflow perspective, you can have Form 2 call a method on Form 1 and provides the new name and color. Form 1 would then add the name to the correct column. There are a number of ways to handle this- one would be to have Form 1 instantiate form 2 then pass in a delegate reference for the method that will take the name and color.

So in Form 1 -

```
Public Sub HandleAdd(name as String, color as String)
' Do Stuff Here.
End Sub

Public Sub AddPlayerButton_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles   AddPlayerButton.Click

Dim frm As New Form2
frm.AfterAdd = AddressOf HandleAdd
frm.Show
End Sub
```

And in Form 2 -

```
Public Property AfterAdd As Action(of String, String)

Public Sub OKButton_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
   If AfterAdd IsNot Nothing Then AfterAdd(playerName.value, playerColor.value)
End Sub
```

Or something like that.